# Get current gridview.rows.count

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a gridview where I set the datasource when the user click a button on the form.
Im trying to get the rowcount of the gridview using the same button_click event, but its returning the rowcount previous to the datasource being set, ie 0.
Im using

```
strCount = gvReturned.Rows.Count.Tostring();
```

Any hints appreciated.

thanks

T

Comment: So you want to get the row count in the button's click event handler where you also bind the grid to it's DataSource? Why don't you use the DataSource directly then? For example: `strCount = DataTable1.Rows.Count.ToString();` (assuming it's a DataTable).

Comment: Can you just get the count from the datasource?  Chances are that even if you do get a count from the `GridView` it'll be the number of _displayed_ rows, not the number of rows in the backing data store.  The `GridView` is just that, a view.  It's a UI element for a specific purpose.  You're better off interacting with the data behind it than with the `GridView` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try listening to the DataSourceChanged event

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
   gvReturned.DataBind()
```

after setting the source but before requesting the count..

Comment: there is not DataBind() in WinForm

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso: Where has OP mentioned that it's Winforms? Actually there's only a GridView control in ASP.NET, the winforms control is called DataGridView.

Comment: OP is talking about Form and not WebForm. There is not Asp.net tag as well. Probably he needs to add Asp.net Tag